# How to append a whole new column to an existing table?

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

As the title says, I'm looking to add a new column to a table that exists which you can see here: https://onetoso.com/PSOTesting/Shane/HTML/customCookieList.html

My blocker right now is the tr does not have a class name so I can't append to each row. I've created a new column header by doing:

This creates a new th so I need to generate the field underneath it as well for each respective row.

`let newHead = document.createElement('th'); newHead.class = 'ot-table-header'; newHead.innerHTML = 'Description'; document.querySelector('tr').appendChild(newHead);`

To add the necessary field I require to the table I have this:

`let newRow = document.createElement('td'); newRow.class = 'ot-cookie-desc-td'; newRow.innerHTML = 'Example text'; document.querySelector('tbody tr').appendChild(newRow);`

This will add 1 td that I require but how would I add to the additional rows that already exist since there is no way to specifically target those? I'm looking to copy the same format as the existing table.

Comment: if you intended to add a column, you need to append a new td element to each row already populating the table. Am I wrong? Did I correctly understand your question? Talking about a new row only, you should append it to the `tbody` element ... `document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(newRow)` .. but your code preceding that was totally meaningless to me

Comment: I've edited the query a bit so it makes sense. I'm not looking to add another row. I'm looking to add a td to each tr so the table follows the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo showing how to add a column to a table already existing in the dom.

The function `addColumn(table, headerText, rowContents)` given a table, the text of the header for the new column and column data contained by each row; just adds the new column to the table as specified by the args.

The demo calls such function inside the `useCase()` that gets triggered when the button gets clicked.

The table used was taken from the link included in your question but to be better focused I stripped off the details that were just adding noise.

It's worthwhile saying that there's no indicators in your tables to select them in a page holding multiple ones. So in absence of ids or a combination of css class that would make a non ambiguos selector, in my demo I just picked it with `document.querySelector('table')`

```js
function useCase(){
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  addColumn(table, 'newColumn', ['NewContentForRow1','NewContentForRow2']);
}

function addColumn(table, headerText, rowContents){  
  
  const newHeaderCol = document.createElement('th');
  newHeaderCol.innerText = headerText;      
  table.querySelector('thead > tr:first-child').append(newHeaderCol);
  
  const tableRows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');
  let iRow = 0;
  for(const tableRow of tableRows){
    const newBodyCol = document.createElement('td');    
    newBodyCol.innerText = rowContents[iRow++];
    tableRow.append(newBodyCol);
  }
}
```

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

button{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption class="ot-scrn-rdr">Strictly Necessary Cookies</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="ot-table-header ot-host">Cookie Subgroup</th>
      <th scope="col" class="ot-table-header ot-cookies">Cookies</th>
      <th scope="col" class="ot-table-header ot-cookies-type">Cookies used</th>
      <th scope="col" class="ot-table-header ot-life-span">Lifespan</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1[A]</td>
      <td>Row1[B]</td>
      <td>Row1[C]</td>
      <td>Row1[D]</td>               
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2[A]</td>
      <td>Row2[B]</td>
      <td>Row2[C]</td>
      <td>Row2[D]</td>               
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="useCase();">Add Column</button>
```